# Problem with configure script

Tags: c, linux, shell, ffmpeg, busybox

I am running into a problem with the `./configure` script for ffmpeg. My linux environment  uses busybox, which only allows for limited set of linux commands. One command which is used in the ffmpeg `./configure` script is `mktemp -u`, the problem here is the busybox for linux does not recognize the -u switch as valid, so it complains about it and breaks the configure process.

This is the relevant code in `./configure` which uses the `mktemp -u` command:

```
if ! check_cmd type mktemp; then
    # simple replacement for missing mktemp
    # NOT SAFE FOR GENERAL USE
    mktemp(){
        echo "${2%XXX*}.${HOSTNAME}.${UID}.$$"
    }
fi

tmpfile(){
    tmp=$(mktemp -u "${TMPDIR}/ffconf.XXXXXXXX")$2 &&
        (set -C; exec > $tmp) 2>/dev/null ||
        die "Unable to create temporary file in $TMPDIR."
    append TMPFILES $tmp
    eval $1=$tmp
}
```

I am not good with bash scripting at all, so I was wondering if anyone one had an idea on how I can force this configure script to not use `mktemp -u` and use the *'replacement'* alternative option that is available in as per the snippet above. Thanks.

btw... simply removing the `-u` switch does not work. Nor does replacing it with `-t`, or `-p`. I believe the `mktemp` has to be bypassed completely.

Comment: Why you want to compile it on busybox? FFMPEG has n number of dependencies. It will ask n number of libraries to compile. even if it successfully configured it will cry while compiling. My suggestion is to use precompiled version or cross compile it according to target requirement.

Comment: Busybox is what is available for the mobile platform (webos) I am dev'ing for. I attempted to cross compile it on my mac but that failed with gcc saying it could not  create an executable file. I cannot find any late version precompiled binaries. I have been googling for days. Any suggestions, because as you stated, it ultimately failed during make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ! check_cmd type mktemp; then
    # simple replacement for missing mktemp
    # NOT SAFE FOR GENERAL USE
    mktemp(){
        echo "${2%XXX*}.${HOSTNAME}.${UID}.$$"
    }
fi
```

To this:

```
#if ! check_cmd type mktemp; then
if true; then # Force the use of mktemp()
    # simple replacement for missing mktemp
    # NOT SAFE FOR GENERAL USE
    mktemp(){
        echo "${2%XXX*}.${HOSTNAME}.${UID}.$$"
    }
fi
```

You could alternatively remove the entire `if` `fi` constructs so that what's left is just the `mktemp()` definition but I'd rather leave them in as a way to remember what needed to be done and in case you need to go back.

Comment: Your solution has gotten me passed the mktemp dilemma. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change the configure script to drop the `-u` option to *mktemp* and remove the `set -C;` (which sets no-clobber mode, and requires the file to be absent; removing the `-u` means you need to remove the `set -C` too).

The MacOS X manual pages for *mktemp(1)* say:

> `-u`      Operate in ``unsafe'' mode.  The temp file will be unlinked before mktemp exits.  This is slightly better than mktemp(3) but still introduces a race condition.  Use of
>                this option is not encouraged.

The generated file name is unlinked by mktemp, and then immediately re-created by the configure script, which is a trifle silly.  Dropping the `-u` means that the file name will already exist, having been created securely.

If the software is something you are going to use often, then report the issue to the developer or maintainer of the software.